# Using Material-UI muiThemeable within the render function of a component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im currently using material-ui for my web app and would like to add themes to it so Im using the `MuiThemeProvider` it comes with to theme it.

The documentation contains [instructions](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes) on how to use custom components with themes but it unfortunately lacks instruction on how to use it from within a render function.

For example, in the the code they use is:

```
import React from 'react';
import muiThemeable from 'material-ui/styles/muiThemeable';

const DeepDownTheTree = (props) => (
  <span style={{color: props.muiTheme.palette.textColor}}>
    Hello World!
  </span>
);

export default muiThemeable()(DeepDownTheTree);
```

Which is fine, but if you need the render function, this wont do. How would I achieve something similar to this? (This wouldnt work, just an example):

```
import React from 'react';
import muiThemeable from 'material-ui/styles/muiThemeable';

class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return muiThemeable()(
      <span style={{color: props.muiTheme.palette.textColor}}>
        Hello World!
      </span>
    )
  }
}

export default muiThemeable()(DeepDownTheTree);
```

This is critical for my application as I manipulate bits of my DOM in the render function before returning the final DOM.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `this.props.muiTheme.palette.textColor` instead?

Comment: I might be mistaken, Ben but while that would work I think you're supposed to take advantage of `muiThemeable` so it can switch colors in realtime when you switch themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent statefull component to your initial stateless component would be

```
import React from 'react';
import muiThemeable from 'material-ui/styles/muiThemeable';

class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <span style={{color: this.props.muiTheme.palette.textColor}}>
        Hello World!
      </span>
    )
  }
}

export default muiThemeable()(DeepDownTheTree);
```

Note that you use the higher order function (that's the muiThemable()) on the entire component, not on just what is returned from the render function.